# Banned for 5 years for overstaying but it wasn't me

Tags: botswana

I have been banned from South Africa for 5 years. Someone used my passport at the border and overstayed. This person did not change my passport names or photo and the ban was issued against my names.

What can I do? After the investigations were done I was told that I am banned, not the other unknown person.

Comment: To clarify, someone impersonating you used your passport to enter SA and was subsequently banned? Was your passport stolen? I’d say you need advice from a lawyer.

Comment: You clearly need a lawyer. The only reason to ban you in this situation would be if you assisted the other person to impersonate you, which I assume is not true. Get a South African immigration lawyer if you ever want to enter the country.

Comment: If you ever wish to enter SA, obtain a SA lawyer to address this issue *right now.* Because you now know what this other person did, the longer you wait the more likely the SA authorities will see you as complicit in this other person's use of your passport.

Comment: Something weird here. How come you were even involved in these investigations if you knew nothing about this?

Comment: Did you allow them to use your passport? Was it stolen?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's related to SA immigration law.